# Issues with the following method in java regarding reading from an input file

Tags: java, adt

Hi guys so I keep getting the following error when I try running my program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Simulation.getJob(Simulation.java:12)
    at Simulation.main(Simulation.java:58)
```

The piece of code I'm working with looks like this:

```
//all of this is under main.
    m = Integer.parseInt( in.nextLine() );
    //make sure the file has stuff in it
    while(in.hasNext()){
        in.useDelimiter("\n");
        //Create an array of type job to keep track of our number of jobs.
        Job[] jobs = new Job[m];



        for(int i = 1; i < m; i++){
         jobs[i] = getJob(in);
         System.out.println(jobs[i]);
        }
    }

//getJob function is here:
public static Job getJob(Scanner in){
    String[] s = in.nextLine().split(" ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
    int d = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
    return new Job(a,d);
    }
```

The data from the in file looks like this
3
2 2
3 4 
5 6

Comment: Please show your input file. It looks like the file does not have data for enough `Job`s.

Comment: ah Yes! So the data file essentially looks like this
3
2 2
3 4
5 6

The format is: that the 3 is on a line by itself and 2 2 are on a line, 34 are on a line, 5 6 are on a line of their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code does not match the input format: when the nested `for` loop is over, the outer `while` loop takes you back to the beginning of the reading code, and tries to read another set of `m` items.

To fix this, simply remove your outer loop:

```
in.useDelimiter("\n");
//Create an array of type job to keep track of our number of jobs.
Job[] jobs = new Job[m];
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    jobs[i] = getJob(in);
    System.out.println(jobs[i]);
}
```

Note that the loop index `i` needs to start at zero, not at `1`, because Java arrays are zero-based.